# TYPO3 - typoscript backlink

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, fluid

I am currently looking all over the web for a solution to create a link back to the referring page.

atm I am just using JS e.g.

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">« back</a>
```

I would like to add the information to which page the link leads back using the page title of the referring page e.g.

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">« back to: <referring-page-title></a>
```

is there any way to create such a backlink with typoscript or fluid?

thx for helping me out, rgds
stooky

Answer (score 0):

You could also check the referrer in TYPO3 but that would lead to the problem that the full cache can't be cached anymore. I woudln't recommend that.

What about misusing e.g. the local storage, write all page information you need into some JS variables, save it into the local storage whenever a link is triggered and use it from there?

Comment: if it is not asked too much, I would appreciate a short sample how to acomplish this task.
maybe I should notice, that I actually want to create this backlink in a detail view of your faboulus tx_news. really love it compared to the old tt_news, respect for an awesome ext.
I want this backlink, as I am using product related news listing, which comes from several different pages to this detail view, and instead of linking the user to a list view I want to link him back to the actual page he was coming from. any the nice bit would be to show him a link that mentions where he goes back to.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are in the page tree you can use something like this:

```
lib.backlink = HMENU
lib.backlink {
    entryLevel = 2
    special = browse
    special.items = up
    wrap = <nav id="backlink">|</nav>

    1 = TMENU
    1.NO.stdWrap.dataWrap = <span>back to:&nbsp;| </span>
}
```

> otherwise

```
renderObj.10 = TEXT
renderObj.10.value = <a href="javascript:history.back()">Go back</a>
```

Comment: cheers elvis, 
the second solution is what I have in use now, but I would like sth. that ads the pagetitle of the referring page like
`<a href="javascript:history.back()">Go back to *referring-page-title*</a>`
and the first solution is not possible, as the referring page could be anywhere in the pagetree :(